# Which demons developed sunlight resistance?

Tags: demon-slayer

In the Kimetsu no Yaiba wikia it states that eventually

> Nezuko Kamado develops sunlight resistance

Is there any other demon like this? Which demons developed sunlight resistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She's the only one. Muzan has waited for nearly a thousand years for a demon like that to appear so that he can absorb it and become truly invincible.

Following is the gist of chapter 127:

> Muzan is visibly shaken after learning of Nezuko. He says there's no more need to look for blue spider lily, Nezuko has the ability that even the 12 moons do not have. He plans to absorb her to gain that ability. The next panels show Muzan's past and how he became a demon.

Answer (score 1):

I think she's the only one who has sunlight resistance. I don't how she develops it and I would want to know too :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is outdated now, because new info appeared in the manga after 2019 , though almost still right

> For a short while Tanjiro (probably just some minutes) Tanjiro becomes a demon and develops sunlight resistance